# How to get from the last maxpool layer to the fc layer?

Tags: deep-learning, convolution

In this demo: http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/demo/mnist.html  the last maxpool layer is 4x4x16 and the fully connected layer 1x1x10.

I do not understand how to get to 10. In my understanding, e.g. I do conv2(option: 'valid') with just one 4x4 filter, stride=1 and no zero padding. The output will be then 1x1x16. If I do more filter the output will be a multiple of 16 (e.g.32)??

Update, my idea is now: Once I have the 1x1x16 vector, I will do 10 one dimensional convolutions. So filter with conv1(option: 'valid') and use 10 filter(vector with length 16). The output will be then a 1x1x10 vector. Kindly let me know, what I am doing right or wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand the concept of "fully connected".  See [this top diagram](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~bolo/shipyard/neural/local.html) for a fully-connected network.  You don't do another convolution.  Instead, you linearize the previous layer: a direct, row-by-row copy of all 16 filters, concatenated into a vector, 256x1.

"Fully connected" means that *every* neuron of one lays is connected to *every* neuron of the other.  You have 256 neurons in this vector, connected (weight) to each of the 10 neurons in the final layer.  That's 2560 weights in all.

Comment: thanks, you are right. I found the convn() function in matlab which also seems to be a good alternative